# How can I prevent or avoid interactive function input from being saved to the minibuffer-history?

Tags: emacs

I have a function that takes in input like so.

```
(interactive
 (list (read-string "Key to use for encryption: ")
 (region-beginning)(region-end)))
```

How can I prevent the inputted string from being saved to minibuffer-history and is there another way to read input that avoids being saved to minibuffer-history?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @fedes.: There is nothing wrong with posting Emacs questions here (or there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `read-passwd`? It was designed for this kind of "secure" input. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-a-Password.html

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily bind `minibuffer-history` to itself:

```
(let ((minibuffer-history minibuffer-history)) (read-string "Key to use: "))
```

After `read-string` returns, `minibuffer-history` is restored to its original value, which will not include whatever `read-string` added to it.

Comment: This solution is very clever and is great for if the user still wants to see what he's typing! The only issue might be that I'm not sure if the key that is entered is stored anywhere else or not though